# How to select a menu item at run item?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I have this code in the click event:

```
MenuItem myItem = new MenuItem("Tab", TabIndex);
Menu1.Items.AddAt(TabIndex, myItem);
myItem.Selected = true;
```

Now for example I click on a button with this click event 5 times it will create 5 menu at run time.

What I want to do is to have another button that when click, it will select any item on the menu (or array of MenuItem).

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MenuItem myItem = Menu1.Items[0];
            }
```

i put 0 u can choose other index depending on what you need.
or...

```
MenuItem myitem = Menu1.SelectedItem;
```

thank you,here is one more way

```
foreach (MenuItem c in Menu1.Items)
            {
                if (c.SomePropertyYouNeed == SomeOtherThingYouNeedToCheck)
                {
                    //your logic here
                }

            }
```

Comment: What if I want to select a different item other than the current item?

Comment: thank you,just edited with 1 more alternative,where u check some property of the item against something you need to be check with like c.Text == "blabla"

Comment: Thanks this is useful for me. :)